# Why "bad URI(is not URI?): http://www.example.com:80index"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm making RSpec test.
Our website like this. It's plain website.
https://somewebsite.com/restaurant
So every time I try to test, it shows this kind of error.

```
$ bundle exec rspec spec/requests/restaurant_spec.rb
Restaurants
  GET /index
    index responds successfully (FAILED - 1)

Failures:

  1) Restaurants GET /index index responds successfully
     Failure/Error: get :index

     URI::InvalidURIError:
       bad URI(is not URI?): http://www.example.com:80index
     # ./spec/requests/restaurant_spec.rb:6:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.00484 seconds (files took 6.41 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure
```

My test code is this.

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe "Restaurants", type: :request do
  describe "GET /index" do
    it "index responds successfully" do
      get :index
      expect(response).to be_success
    end
  end
end
```

And my application code here.

```
  def index
    @q = Restaurant.ransack(params[:q])
    if params[:q].present?
      @all_restaurants = @q.result(distinct: true).page(params[:page])
    else
      @all_restaurants = Restaurant.page(params[:page])
    end
  end
```

BTW my routing is this.

```
scope "(:locale)", locale: /en|ja/ do
  get 'restaurant/' => 'restaurant#index'
  get 'restaurant/:id' => 'restaurant#show'
end
```

Why this error happens? Please let me know. Thanks in advance.

## Appendix

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.5.0p0 (2017-12-25 revision 61468) [x86_64-darwin17]
$ rails -v
Rails 5.2.2

RSpec
    rspec-core (3.10.1)
      rspec-support (~> 3.10.0)
    rspec-expectations (3.10.1)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.10.0)
    rspec-mocks (3.10.2)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.10.0)
    rspec-rails (5.0.1)
```

Comment: Add your routes.rb file code for more details. You need to give the route in /index place, if your route is /restaurant, you need to give that route name, not the action name

Comment: @honey Thanks for the comment. I just added route.rb configurations in description. Could you explain detailed code modification?

Answer (score 0):

I think this error is related to the `describe` block in RSpec. Change `"Restaurants"` to just `Restaurant` (singular and without the quotation marks).

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Restaurant, type: :request do
  describe "GET /index" do
    it "index responds successfully" do
      get :index
      expect(response).to be_success
    end
  end
end
```

Also, I think you'll have to change your routes to get this to work properly. Since you have a resourceful controller, use **resource routing**:

```
scope "(:locale)", locale: /en|ja/ do
  resources :restaurants, only: %i[index show]
end
```

Should give you the routes `/restaurants` and `/restaurants/:id` with your desired locales, which is the [Rails convention](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default) for this type of routing. And it'll also allow you to use `:index` and `:show` in your RSpec tests.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I changed in accordance with your advice.  But still same error come up. Any idea?

Comment: Well, if none of these works, I'm out of ideas. But I guess one last try would be changing `get :index` to `get restaurants_path`. Could you please try and see if it works?

Comment: Just replaced. Unfortunately, it didn't work. But error changed slightly."Failure/Error: expect(response).to be_success
       expected `#<ActionDispatch::TestResponse...@ip=nil>>.success?` to be truthy, got false"
Why it got false?

Comment: When you run this application in a local server and access this page, does it work or is there any errors?

Comment: Basically I test in the daytime. Every time I start up 'rails s' and access to 'http://localhost:3000/restaurant', it shows smoothly and no errors comes up. That's strange.